# WPF Menu Items Styles

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, menu, styles

I have an application resource of the following

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource windowTextBackColor}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource windowsTextForeColor}"/>
</Style>
```

So all the text blocks in my application should assume those colours.

However the Menu and its containing MenuItems on my Main Window does not take these colours?

I have to do the XAML

for it to assume those colours, Is there a reason why setting a style that targets Text blocks does not work?

Thanks

Comment: Can I recommend marking some of your questions as answered? It promotes community and people will be more inclined to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to style the menu and menuitems separately. A `MenuItem` is a `HeaderedContentControl`, and its Header property is not a `TextBlock`, but an `object`, so it wouldn't be affected by a style for TextBlock.

You might also try changing that style to target `Control` instead of TextBlock. (Control is where `Foreground` and `Background` are defined.) I can't say for sure that it'll work, but if it does, it'll make every Control (TextBlocks, MenuItems, Buttons...) have those background and foreground colors.

Also, you might consider using `BasedOn` so that you can "inherit" the styles. If you don't, then styles defined farther up the hierarchy won't affect controls that have a style defined lower in the hierarchy. Basically, the lower ones mask the higher ones, unless you used `BasedOn`. Use it in this fashion:

```
BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type <your type here>}}"
```

Comment: yes.. and since its `Header` property is an `object`, you can also try `HeaderTemplate` to include `TextBlock`